# some questions about Facebook Graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, search

I have been doing extensive research on facebook graph api and still have several issues that are unclear to me.

1. I searched in FACEBOOK API for this question but I didn't find good information about 
   where I can found "Facebook limitations"  ( ex. no. sending messages per day , searching , creating events , invitations ) ?

2.Sorry for asking this question again in forum but really I would like to know if there is new way that can solved my problem . 
about sending private message to friends through graph api instead of using Send Dialog?

1. Is there is way to fill "To,Message" fields in Send Dialog as default values?
2. inviting friends to event through api it's possible ?
3. how can I read posting/comments on friends wall without getting specific permission from my friends  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I searched in FACEBOOK API for this question but I didn't find good
>   information about where I can found "Facebook limitations" ( ex. no.
>   sending messages per day , searching , creating events , invitations )
>   ?

There really aren't any - except I haven't seen a known API for searching feeds of a user.

> 2.Sorry for asking this question again in forum but really I would like to know if there is new way that can solved my problem . about
>   sending private message to friends through graph api instead of using
>   Send Dialog?
>
> Is there is way to fill "To,Message" fields in Send Dialog as default
>   values?
>
> inviting friends to event through api it's possible ?

All possible - On any client, if you have an oauth token, you can always send messages to the user, without bubbling the To, Message dialogues. Or, if you have them on the server, your client can ask the server to post those messages non-interactively!

You need certain permissions for authorization before you attempt reading the feeds. Facebook does document the default app permissions you have.

> how can I read posting/comments on friends wall without getting
>   specific permission from my friends ?

Comment: Thank you 
could you explain more 
about sending private message through api ( I'm using Restfb )

Comment: You **cannot** set the `message` field when using the [Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/), and you should be careful when sending *automated* messages. If the Send Dialog is all you need, then stick to that!